# too long time for response in mongodb if field value is not available

Tags: php, mongodb

I have Inserted records in mongodb collection/table. everything working fine if i pass data which is available in collection like StoreId = 1

**Problem:** if i search data which is not available in collection like StoreId=3 then it is taking too long time to response why???? How do i simplify this issue?

**Insert Data:**

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array("StoreId" => "1","StoreName" => "abc");
$data[] = array("StoreId" => "2","StoreName" => "xyz");
$db->test->insertMany($data);
```

**Fetch Records:**

```
$arrFind = array(
                    '$and' => array(
                        array(
                            'StoreId' => "1"
                        ),
                        array(
                            'StoreName' => array(
                                        '$regex' => '^ab',
                                        '$options' => 'i'
                                    )
                        )
                    )
                );

$projection =  array("_id" => false);
$result = $db->test->find($arrFind,['limit'=>$data['Count'], 'projection' => $projection ]);
$array1 = iterator_to_array($result, false);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
```

above example working find returns output very quickly, but if i pass StoreId=3 then it is taking too long time to response blank output.

**Mongodb:**

```
db.test.find( { StoreId: "1" } ).pretty() //returns output quickly
db.test.find( { StoreId: "3" } ).pretty() //taking too-long time for blank output.
```

**explain:**

```
db.test.find( { StoreId: "3" } ).explain(true)
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "mydb.test",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "StoreId" : {
                                "$eq" : "3"
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "StoreId" : {
                                        "$eq" : "3"
                                }
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 0,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 35083,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 6816823,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "StoreId" : {
                                        "$eq" : "3"
                                }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 34087,
                        "works" : 6816825,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 6816824,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 53988,
                        "restoreState" : 53988,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "docsExamined" : 6816823
                },
                "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "Neha-PC",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.6.3",
                "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi looking at you question , it examined around 6816823 record , it seems there is no secondary index has been created

you need to create the index on "StoreId" reduced the lookup

u can check what all the index has been created for your collection using following command

```
db.test.getIndexKeys();
```

To create index you can use following command

```
db.test.createIndex( { StoreId: 1 } );
```

after creating the index on your collection try to run the query , it should be fast

for more info
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have any indexes which can be used for this query, so MongoDB need to check every document in the collection. The collection scan ("COLLSCAN") is pretty slow on big collections. You need to create an index from `StoreId` element.